# JavaScript Regex not detecting

Tags: javascript, regex

I attempted to create a Regex that matches Opening HTML Tags.

```
<\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^'\">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)>
```

Is what I have come up with. It works great in RegexPal.com http://gyazo.com/cef34f653c4a3483a31394330455c0cf
But as soon as I try to use it on some text in JS (both Chrome and Node) this happens: http://gyazo.com/0c938ee289c1632f3f576aaccda1f81e

Rules is defined like that:

```
var Rules = [
    new RegExp("<\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^'\">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/>"),
    new RegExp("<\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^'\">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)>"),
    new RegExp("</\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^'\">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)>")
];
```

and Content is defined like that:

```
var Content = "<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><title>derp</title></head><body><div class=\"derp\"><!--this is formatted terribly -->derp<br /></div></body></html>";
```

Comment: You know what they say - if you've got one problem and try to solve it with RegEx, now you've got two problems.

Comment: Using reg exp to match html is a bad bad bad idea.

Comment: Well I was just playing around a little with the HTML syntax and tried to create a Tokenizer.

Comment: you can use DOM to parse it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is if you want to use `RegExp()` you need to double up the `\`.

```
 new RegExp("<\\w+((\\s+...
```

It would be better to drop the RegExp and just use `/regExp/`

```
var Rules = [
    /<\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^'\">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/>/,
    /<\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^'\">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)>"/,
    /</\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^'\">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)>/
];
```

Answer (score 0):

When used inside a string, you need to escape `\` to `\\`, otherwise you are just escaping whatever comes afterwards.

Either escape the `\` characters or use the `/regex/` syntax for defining a regex.