# RegEx Javascript replace?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to make a filter which has a lot of options that get listed in the top of the filter box, now, I'm trying to add the countries and I decided to use regex. But I can't get it to work, for some reason it replaces in the middle of the string instead of the beginning.

JS Code:

```
function countryCheck(object) {
    var filter = document.getElementById("search_filter");
    var re = new RegExp("<b>Location<\/b>:\s[a-zA-Z\s]+\s\|\s");
    filter.innerHTML = filter.innerHTML.replace(re, ("<b>Location</b>: " + object.value.replace("&nbsp;&nbsp;", "") + " | "));
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id='search_filter'><b>Filter</b>: <b>Location</b>: Anywhere | <b>Player Slots</b>: >=0/>=0</div>
<br />

<select class='select' style='width:100%;' onchange='countryCheck(this);'>
    <option>Anywhere</option>
    <option>Europe</option>
    <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;Sweden</option>
    <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;Germany</option>
    <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;United Kingdom</option>
    <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;France</option>
    <option>North America</option>
    <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;Canada</option>
    <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;United States</option>
    <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;Mexico</option>
</select>
```

jsFiddle showing what the problem is: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9m2hp/)

I'm trying to make so it replaces the current `<b>Location</b>: [some country] |` with `<b>Location</b>: [some other country] |`

Comment: Why would you do this with regex? Why not give the location value some `class` or `id` and replace the content directly?

Comment: Your problem is with \/ and \s See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611956/javascript-regex-not-detecting/16612041

Comment: Unrelated side note: You might want to take a look at [`<optgroup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FElement%2Foptgroup).

Comment: Didn't know about optgroup, but still, I want the user to be able to select "Europe".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use a regex for this but put your target into a tag of its own like:

```
<div id="search_filter">
     <b>Filter</b>: <b>Location</b>: 
     <span id="search_filter_location">Anywhere</span>
      | <b>Player Slots</b>: >=0/>=0
</div>
```

and then replace the content inside this tag only like:

```
function countryCheck(object) {
    var filter = document.getElementById("search_filter_location");
    filter.innerHTML = object.value.replace("&nbsp;&nbsp;", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace in the beginning of your string just use `^` at the beginning of your regex, which matches the beginning (`$` matches the end)

So your code would be:

```
function countryCheck(object) {
    var filter = document.getElementById("search_filter");
    var re = new RegExp("<b>Location<\/b>:\s[a-zA-Z\s]+\s\|\s");
    filter.innerHTML = filter.innerHTML.replace(re, ("<b>Location</b>: " + object.value.replace(/^(\s){2}/, "") + " | "));
}
```

**Edit:** If you want to replace any spaces where it's 2 or more spaces atthe begging on your string, you could use this as your regex: `/^(\s){2,}/`

Answer (score 0):

When you make a regular expression object via the RegExp constructor and a string, you must **double** the backslashes.  It's really better to just use native syntax:

```
    var re = /<b>Location<\/b>:\s[a-zA-Z\s]+\s\|\s/;
```

In your code, the `\s` subexpressions were being turned into just plain `s` by the JavaScript tokenizer as it recognized the string constant.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function countryCheck(object) {
    var filter = document.getElementById("search_filter");
    var re = /(<b>Location<\/b>:\s)([^|]+)(|)/;
    filter.innerHTML = filter.innerHTML.replace(re, ("$1" + object.value.replace("&nbsp;&nbsp;", "") + " $3"));
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qaDGz/)